# Loading JNI .DLL, GCC compiled works, G++ compiled fails

Tags: gcc, java-native-interface, g++, mingw

I have a simple JNI .DLL that I am trying to use in a test Java application.  It is a `.c` file that consists of a couple functions, with the header generated by `javah`. (I am compiling using MinGW btw)

If I compile and link this code with GCC, I can load the .DLL just fine with System.loadLibrary(), and use it.  If I compiled it with G++ however, `loadLibrary()` will fail with the dreaded "UnsatisfiedLinkError".

This is my GCC line:

> gcc -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\include\win32" -shared -o TestJNI.dll TestJNI.c

This is my G++ line:

> g++ -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\include\win32" -shared -o TestJNI.dll TestJNI.c

Any thoughts?  I am assuming something is different in the way G++ names the functions, but I don't know what...

Comment: Can you check the exported function names in the dll and see if there's any difference between the two? You can do this with depwalker or objdump or dumpbin etc.

Comment: THANK YOU greatwolf!  I downloaded depwalker, and it immediately told me that I was missing a referenced .DLL (  libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll ).  That was what I needed to know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Greatwolf's tip:

It turns out I had a reference to another shared library, libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll.  I added the "-static" flag to my G++ compile, and the reference went away.  Now it loads fine from Java!

And just in case anybody else is wrestling with JNI hell; I really should have looked at the Java exception more closely, because it actually mentioned the issue ( "Can't find dependent libraries" ).  I had assumed this meant that it couldn't find/read MY library, but this actually referred to the other .DLL dependency.

Comment: Note you can also use `-static-libgcc` to force it to link against the static version. Additionally, if your library uses C++ code using the standard library you can also force a static link to that using `-static-libstdc++`.

Answer (score 1):

All JNI exported functions need `extern "C"` when compiled as C++.

Comment: I assume you are referring to adding extern "C" in the function implementations ( the .C file )?  I had thought this was the issue too, but adding it seems to have no effect on my problem.